# Find closest date in array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I have an array with days in it. Each day is an object, for example:

`{day_year: "2012", day_month: "08", day_number: "03", day_name: "mon"}`

I have also added a timestamp attribute to each day object, by using:

```
function convertDays() {
    var max_i = days.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < max_i; i++) {
        var tar_i = days[i];
        tar_i.timestamp = new Date(tar_i.day_year, tar_i.day_month, tar_i.day_number);
    }
}
```

The days in the array are arbitrary, so there is no real logic to them.

Now I want to find the two closest days to any given date. So if the array with days contains

- August 2, 2012
- August 4, 2012
- August 23, 2012

And I search for August 11, 2012, I want it to return August 4, 2012 and August 23, 2012.

I have tried using an answer from another question, that looks like this:

```
function findClosest(a, x) {
    var lo, hi;
    for(var i = a.length; i--;) {
        if(a[i] <= x && (lo === undefined || lo < a[i])) lo = a[i];
        if(a[i] >= x && (hi === undefined || hi > a[i])) hi = a[i];
    }
    return [lo, hi];
}
```

However, this returns `unidentified`.

What would be the most efficient (least processor/memory intensive way) to achieve this?

**Edit: "However, how are those results "strange"? Could you provide an example of your code and data?"**

I'm now using the following to generate an array of dates:

```
var full_day_array = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + i);
    full_day_array.push({day_year: d.getFullYear().toString(), day_month: (d.getMonth() + 1).toString(), day_number: d.getDate().toString()});
}
```

The strange part is, using the code below, this only works for an array of 10 dates or shorter. Whenever I use an array of 11 or more dates, the results become unexpected.

For instance: using an array of 15 dates, starting on August 6, 2012, to August 21, 2012. If I then call `findClosest(full_day_array, new Date("30/07/2012");` you would expect it to return `{nextIndex: 0, prevIndex: -1}`. However, it returns `{nextIndex: 7, prevIndex: -1}`. Why?

```
function findClosest(objects, testDate) {
    var nextDateIndexesByDiff = [],
        prevDateIndexesByDiff = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        var thisDateStr = [objects[i].day_month, objects[i].day_number, objects[i].day_year].join('/'),
            thisDate    = new Date(thisDateStr),
            curDiff     = testDate - thisDate;

        curDiff < 0
            ? nextDateIndexesByDiff.push([i, curDiff])
            : prevDateIndexesByDiff.push([i, curDiff]);
    }

    nextDateIndexesByDiff.sort(function(a, b) { return a[1] < b[1]; });
    prevDateIndexesByDiff.sort(function(a, b) { return a[1] > b[1]; });


    var nextIndex;
    var prevIndex;

    if(nextDateIndexesByDiff.length < 1) {
        nextIndex = -1;
    } else {
        nextIndex = nextDateIndexesByDiff[0][0];
    }
    if(prevDateIndexesByDiff.length < 1) {
        prevIndex = -1;
    } else {    
        prevIndex = prevDateIndexesByDiff[0][0];
    }
    return {nextIndex: nextIndex, prevIndex: prevIndex};
}
```

Comment: Why do you have them in that format? Can you change the format to be timestamps so you can parse them to proper date objects more easily?

Comment: I could indeed change them to timestamps, for example by looping through the days and adding an attribute 'timestamp' to them: `days[i].timestamp = new Date(days[i].day_year, days[i].day_month, days[i].day_number);` Would that help?

Comment: If you want to speak about efficiency then you should define how do you suppose to use it. For example it matters whether you need to find one closest date in one set of dates or you will have same set of dates and you will search over them several times.

Comment: I have up to five sets of days, each containing about 200 days. Then I have up to 100 dates for which I have to find the two closest days.

Comment: Should be `typeof lo == "undefined"`

Comment: Note that the Date constructor takes a string in `MM/DD/YYYY` format. Unhelpfully, `new Date("30/07/2012");` evaluates to the string "Invalid Date", rather than throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, no matter how long the array of dates is:

```
function newFindClosest(dates, testDate) {
    var before = [];
    var after = [];
    var max = dates.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        var tar = dates[i];
        var arrDate = new Date(tar.day_year, tar.day_month, tar.day_number);
        // 3600 * 24 * 1000 = calculating milliseconds to days, for clarity.
        var diff = (arrDate - testDate) / (3600 * 24 * 1000);
        if(diff > 0) {
            before.push({diff: diff, index: i});
        } else {
            after.push({diff: diff, index: i});
        }
    }
    before.sort(function(a, b) {
        if(a.diff < b.diff) {
            return -1;
        }
        if(a.diff > b.diff) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    after.sort(function(a, b) {
        if(a.diff > b.diff) {
            return -1;
        }
        if(a.diff < b.diff) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
    return {datesBefore: before, datesAfter: after};
}
```

Answer (score 33):

You can easily use the [`sort` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a custom comparator function:

```
// assuming you have an array of Date objects - everything else is crap:
var arr = [new Date(2012, 7, 1), new Date(2012, 7, 4), new Date(2012, 7, 5), new Date(2013, 2, 20)];
var diffdate = new Date(2012, 7, 11);

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    var distancea = Math.abs(diffdate - a);
    var distanceb = Math.abs(diffdate - b);
    return distancea - distanceb; // sort a before b when the distance is smaller
});

// result:
[2012-08-05, 2012-08-04, 2012-08-01, 2013-03-20]
```

To get only results before or after the `diffdate`, you can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array for that:

```
var beforedates = arr.filter(function(d) {
    return d - diffdate < 0;
}),
    afterdates = arr.filter(function(d) {
    return d - diffdate > 0;
});
```

---

If you have your custom array with the `{the_date_object: new Date(...)}` objects, you will need to adapt the sort algorithm with

```
    var distancea = Math.abs(diffdate - a.the_date_object);
    var distanceb = Math.abs(diffdate - b.the_date_object);
```

Comment: +1: Nice usage of `sort()`. However, won't this result in a O(N log N) runtime?

Comment: Sure, that depends on whether you want to get all dates in their order or just need a selection algorithm.

Comment: I like this, the `filter()` approach hadn't occurred to me. Would also translate nicely to [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) et al.

Answer (score 15):

If you use an array of  `Date` objects instead of your self-defined structure it can be achieved very easily in O(N):

```
var testDate = new Date(...);
var bestDate = days.length;
var bestDiff = -(new Date(0,0,0)).valueOf();
var currDiff = 0;
var i;

for(i = 0; i < days.length; ++i){
   currDiff = Math.abs(days[i] - testDate);
   if(currDiff < bestDiff){
       bestDate = i;
       bestDiff = currDiff;
   }   
}

/* the best date will be days[bestDate] */
```

If the array is sorted it can be achieved in O(log N) with binary search.

#### Edit: "it is crucial that I find both the closest match *before* and *after* the date"

```
var testDate = new Date(...);

var bestPrevDate = days.length;
var bestNextDate = days.length;

var max_date_value = Math.abs((new Date(0,0,0)).valueOf());

var bestPrevDiff = max_date_value;
var bestNextDiff = -max_date_value;

var currDiff = 0;
var i;

for(i = 0; i < days.length; ++i){
   currDiff = testDate - days[i].the_date_object;
   if(currDiff < 0 && currDiff > bestNextDiff){
   // If currDiff is negative, then testDate is more in the past than days[i].
   // This means, that from testDate's point of view, days[i] is in the future
   // and thus by a candidate for the next date.
       bestNextDate = i;
       bestNextDiff = currDiff;
   }
   if(currDiff > 0 && currDiff < bestPrevDiff){
   // If currDiff is positive, then testDate is more in the future than days[i].
   // This means, that from testDate's point of view, days[i] is in the past
   // and thus by a candidate for the previous date.
       bestPrevDate = i;
       bestPrevDiff = currDiff;
   }   

}
/* days[bestPrevDate] is the best previous date, 
   days[bestNextDate] is the best next date */
```

Comment: I can add Date objects to the array, but the Dates would have to be sub-objects because each day-object also contains other (irrelevant for this question) information. Is your method also capable of searching through attributes of objects in an array and returning the objects containing the (closest matching) attributes?

Comment: Also, it is crucial that I find both the closest match *before* and *after* the target date, so I must always end up with two dates, unless the target date is before the first day in the array, or after the last.

Comment: @ReinoudSchuijers: Added closest match. If your objects contain other information and the `Date` is a specific property (lets say, `days[i].the_date_object`, then my method is capable of doing so.

Comment: @ReinoudSchuijers: The method provided above doesn't need sorted arrays. However, how are those results "strange"? Could you provide an example of your code and data?

Comment: Reinoud - remember, the procedure returns the **indexes** of the results you want in the original array, not the objects themselves.

Comment: I understand. However, `days[4]` is undefined (the array's length is 4, so the last object in the array is `days[3]`) and `days[0]` isn't the best next date because it's actually in the past.

Comment: @ReinoudSchuijers: Silly me, I have accidentally used a wrong comparison. Also the start values for `bestNextDiff` and `bestPrevDiff` were wrong.

Answer (score 9):

You Can try it like this

```
var dates = [
'July 16, 1995 03:24:00',
'Aug 18, 1995 03:24:00',
'August 19, 1995 03:24:00',
'September 17, 1995 03:24:00',
'September 14, 1995 03:24:00',
'August 18, 1995 03:24:00',
'July 16, 1995 03:24:00',
'December 15, 1995 03:24:00',
'July 13, 1995 03:24:00',
]

var temp = dates.map(d => Math.abs(new Date() - new Date(d).getTime()));
var idx = temp.indexOf(Math.min(...temp));
console.log(dates[idx]);
```

Answer (score 7):

[Zeta's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1139697/zeta) answer is excellent, but I was interested in how you'd approach this if you wanted to know the nearest N objects in either direction. Here's my stab:

```
var objects = [
    { day_year: "2012",
      day_month: "08",
      day_number: "02"
    },
    { day_year: "2012",
      day_month: "08",
      day_number: "04"
    },
    { day_year: "2012",
      day_month: "08",
      day_number: "23"
    }
];

var testDate = new Date('08/11/2012'),
    nextDateIndexesByDiff = [],
    prevDateIndexesByDiff = [];

for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    var thisDateStr = [objects[i].day_month, objects[i].day_number, objects[i].day_year].join('/'),
        thisDate    = new Date(thisDateStr),
        curDiff     = testDate - thisDate;

    curDiff < 0
        ? nextDateIndexesByDiff.push([i, curDiff])
        : prevDateIndexesByDiff.push([i, curDiff]);
}

nextDateIndexesByDiff.sort(function(a, b) { return a[1] < b[1]; });
prevDateIndexesByDiff.sort(function(a, b) { return a[1] > b[1]; });

console.log(['closest future date', objects[nextDateIndexesByDiff[0][0]]]);
console.log(['closest past date', objects[prevDateIndexesByDiff[0][0]]]);
```

Comment: For some reason, this works for me and Zeta's answer didn't. [edit]: it worked before you changed it. Now I get an error (unexpected token ;) at `...? nextDateIndexesByDiff.push([i, curDiff]);
        : prevDateIndexesByDiff...`

Comment: Apologies, I added a syntax error when switching the if/else for a ternary.

Comment: That's ok. And for future dates, the logs could be improved by doing this: `if(nextDateIndexesByDiff.length < 1) {
 console.log("No future dates");
} else {
 console.log(['closest future date', objects[nextDateIndexesByDiff[0][0]]]);
}
if(prevDateIndexesByDiff.length < 1) {
 console.log("No dates in the past");
} else { 
 console.log(['closest past date', objects[prevDateIndexesByDiff[0][0]]]);
}` otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: There still seems to be a problem with this method. Whenever the array of dates is longer than 10, things go wrong. I use the following to generate the array: `for(var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
 var d = new Date();
 d.setDate(d.getDate() + i);
 full_day_array.push({day_year: d.getFullYear().toString(), day_month: (d.getMonth() + 1).toString(), day_number: d.getDate().toString()});
}`

Comment: See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what we use:

This function looks in *array* for the item which has the closest date (named *dateParam*) to *dateToCompare*.

For each *item*[*dateParam*], returns array's element which has the closest date to dateToCompare

```
getClosestDateInArray (array, dateParam, dateToCompare) {
  let minDiff = null;
  let mostAccurateDate = array[0];
  array.map((item) => {
    const diff = Math.abs(moment(dateToCompare).diff(item[dateParam], 'minutes', true));
    if (!minDiff || diff < minDiff) {
      minDiff = diff;
      mostAccurateDate = item
    }
  });
  return mostAccurateDate;
}
```

**This solution require momentJS library**