# Angularjs - match a date from an array of dates to find the closest match to display in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi please see my plunkr below

https://plnkr.co/edit/8cJZsb?p=preview

I have $scope.data which looks like this

```
 $scope.data = [  
    {  
      "projectedStart":"2017-01-20T00:00:00"      
   },
   {  
      "projectedStart":"2017-02-09T00:00:00"      
   }
];
```

and $scope.possibleDates that look like this

```
   $scope.possibleDates = [{  
      "projectedStartDate":"2017-01-25T00:00:00",
      "dateName":"January - Week 4 (20/10)"
   },
   {  
      "projectedStartDate":"2017-02-01T00:00:00",
      "dateName":"February (6/10)"
   },
   {  
      "projectedStartDate":"2017-03-01T00:00:00",
      "dateName":"March (0/2)"
   },
   {  
      "projectedStartDate":"2017-04-05T00:00:00",
      "dateName":"April (2/5)"
   }]
```

On the front end dropdown list, I want to be able to display the possibleDates that match closest to the 'projectedStart' date in $scope.data.

I am thinking of doing an angular foreach and looping through each projectedStart date in $scope.data and somehow compare it with each of the dates in $scope.possibleDates and updating $scope.Data's projectedStart with the closest match? Failing miserably so far.

Would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction

Comment: When you say 'The possibleDates that match closest to the ...', How many are you looking for? 2 of the closest matches? 3?

Comment: I'm looking for 1 date that matches or is closest

Answer (score 0):

Look's like you need to look into [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It's a spectacular library for date parsing, formatting, and comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a watcher on possibleDates, and when they change you compute the list that you are after.

The list can be easily written with tools like moment and underscore.

```
const projectedDate = moment($scope.data[0].projectedStartDate);
const sortedPossibleDates = _.chain($scope.possibleDates)
   .each((possibleDate) => {
     possibleDate.diff = projectedDate.difference('seconds');
   });
   .sortBy('diff')
   .value()
```

And voila, the sortedPossibleDates[0] is your best answer

Answer (score 0):

A basic sort function should be able to order the possible dates by how close they are to the chosen start date. Just use new Date(ISOString) to get the numerical timestamps.

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11796365/6452040

Answer (score 0):

If you put a function in script.js like this, which finds the closest date (before or after):

```
$scope.closestStartDate = function(startDate) {
    var smallestDifferenceInDates = 1000000000000;//impossibly large value
    var closestDateName = 'tmp';
    var date = new Date(startDate);

   for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys($scope.possibleDates).length; i++) {
      var projectedDate = new Date($scope.possibleDates[i].projectedStartDate);
      if (Math.abs(date.getTime() - projectedDate.getTime()) < smallestDifferenceInDates) {
        smallestDifferenceInDates = Math.abs(date.getTime() - projectedDate.getTime());
      closestDateName = $scope.possibleDates[i].dateName;
    }
  }
  return closestDateName;
}
```

Then change your template code to this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in data">
    <td>
        {{ closestStartDate(d.projectedStart) }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

You'll get the closest date from $scope.possibleDates (Math.abs() gets the distance between the two, if you want dates after you can leave that off).