# Finding date closest to today from array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have parsed a CSV that slices like this:

```
data[0]
>>Date:08/23/2018, Organizer:RadioShack, Event:Promotion
```

I found a somewhat helpful question in: [Find closest date in array with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795266/find-closest-date-in-array-with-javascript), however I had trouble adapting it from an array of dates to dates stored within an array of objects. I have dates from `data[0]` to `data[10]`. It's not a terribly long dataset, however I would like to code it better than my current crude approach:

```
var dateArray = [];
dateArray[0] = data[0].Date;
dateArray[1] = data[1].Date;
…

console.log(dateArray.filter(function(d) {return d - today > 0; }))
```

That gives me all dates after today's date, which is a start, but I'm still falling short on finding the date closest to today.

**Question:** I thought maybe I could just write a for loop to give me that array faster, but I still wonder: is there a way I can find the date closest to today's date from an array of objects and store that date in:

```
var closestEventDate = ???
```

Comment: Sort the dates in the filtered Array ascending and take the first date from it

Comment: @KooiInc - That's rather more work than necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could reduce your dateArray to the date closest to today:

```
 const today = new Date();
 const closest = data.reduce((a, b) => a.Date - today < b.Date - today ? a : b);
```

Live Example:

```js
var now = Date.now();
var ONE_DAY_IN_MS = 86400000;
function randomDate() {
  return new Date(now + (5 * ONE_DAY_IN_MS - Math.round(Math.random() * 10 * ONE_DAY_IN_MS)));
}
var data = [
  {Date: randomDate()},
  {Date: randomDate()},
  {Date: randomDate()},
  {Date: randomDate()},
  {Date: randomDate()},
  {Date: randomDate()},
  {Date: randomDate()},
  {Date: randomDate()},
  {Date: randomDate()}
];

console.log("Entries:");
data.forEach(function(entry) {
  console.log(entry.Date.toISOString());
});

const today = new Date();
const closest = data.reduce((a, b) => a.Date - today < b.Date - today ? a : b);

console.log("today", today.toISOString());
console.log("closest", closest.Date.toISOString());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or the closest *after* today:

```
const today = new Date();
const closest = data.reduce((a, b) => {
  const adiff = a.Date - today;
  return adiff > 0 && adiff < b.Date - today ? a : b;
});
```

Live Example:

```js
var now = Date.now();
var ONE_DAY_IN_MS = 86400000;
function randomDate() {
  return new Date(now + (5 * ONE_DAY_IN_MS - Math.round(Math.random() * 10 * ONE_DAY_IN_MS)));
}
var data = [
  {Date: randomDate()},
  {Date: randomDate()},
  {Date: randomDate()},
  {Date: randomDate()},
  {Date: randomDate()},
  {Date: randomDate()},
  {Date: randomDate()},
  {Date: randomDate()},
  {Date: randomDate()}
];

console.log("Entries:");
data.forEach(function(entry) {
  console.log(entry.Date.toISOString());
});

const today = new Date();
const closest = data.reduce((a, b) => {
  const adiff = a.Date - today;
  return adiff > 0 && adiff < b.Date - today ? a : b;
});

console.log("today", today.toISOString());
console.log("closest", closest.Date.toISOString());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Nice to see a **valid** use of `reduce`!

Comment: @JonasWilms Not sure why, but closest after today only worked properly for me when I switched `&& adiff < b.Date - today` to `&& adiff > b.Date - today`;

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jonas' answer. Similar approach using [dayjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs) library

```
arrayOfDates.reduce((a, b) => dayjs(a.Date).isAfter(dayjs(b.Date)) ? a : b);
```